# How to manipulate array in following scenarion?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

My array named `$email_ids`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => abc@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => lmn@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_email] => pqr@gmail.com
        )

)
```

I want to convert it to array in followinf form:

```
Array
    (
[0] => abc@gmail.com
[1] => lmn@gmail.com
[2] => pqr@gmail.com

    )
```

How should I get this in an optimum way?

Comment: tried anything? Otherwise your question will be flagged as too broad or opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

```
array_map(function($x){return $x['user_email'];}, $email_ids)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `foreach`

```
$newarr = array();
foreach($yourarray as $k=>$arr)
{
 $newarr[]=$arr['user_email'];
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/122244)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$temp = array();

foreach($arr as $val){
    $temp[] = $val['user_email'];
}

var_dump($temp);
```